# Can't find value of row

Tags: php, mysql, row

This is my PHP code:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$userInfo = json_decode($json);
$id = $userInfo->id_user;

include "DatabaseManager.php";
$db = new DatabaseManager();
$username = $db->getInfoUser($id);
```

and

```
  function getInfoUser($id)
  {
      $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", DatabaseManager::DATABASE_NAME);
      $sqlCommand = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = '$id'";
      $result =$connection->query($sqlCommand);
      if($result->num_rows >0){
          while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
              echo json_encode(['username' => $row['username'],"url_profile_img"=> $row['img_profile']]);
          }
      }
  }
```

This code returns the value of `$row['username']` without a problem, but `$row['img_profile']` returns null!
`img_profile` in database exists but returns null.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not select img_profile in your SQL...

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = '$id'
```

perhaps

```
SELECT username, img_profile FROM users WHERE id = '$id'
```

It's also worth looking into how to use prepared statements to help protect your code.